# Impose a condition on a function in a loop

Tags: conditional, infinite-loop

I am trying to calculate something in the following code and I need to omit the final values which are going to be infinity.obviously I want to extract the answers of H2[s] which are zero.

```
Clear[\[CapitalLambda], x, x1, y, y1, z, L, D1, D2, dg, d1, d2, d3, \
d4, M, s]
L = 3;
d1 = 1;
d2 = 2;
d3 = 4;
d4 = 3;
D1 = d1 E^-s + d3 E^s;
D2 = d2 E^-s + d4 E^s;
dg = d1 + d2 + d3 + d4;
smin = -1; smax = 1; \[CapitalDelta]s = 0.1;

x1 = NSolve[(2 \[CapitalLambda]^3 + 
2 \[CapitalLambda]^2* 
dg) x^2 - ((D2* z^-1 + 
D1* z) (\[CapitalLambda]^2 + \[CapitalLambda] (dg)) + (\
\[CapitalLambda] *z^2 - \[CapitalLambda] *(D2)^2 *z^-2)) x + D2 *z - 
D1 *(D2)^2 * z^-1 == 0, x];

Y1 = NSolve[
y - ((z^(L - 2) + 
M*(D2/D1)^L*(D1)^2 *
z^(-L + 2))/((z^L + 
M*(D2/D1)^L *z^-L) (\[CapitalLambda]^2 + \[CapitalLambda]*
dg)) /. 
M -> z^(2 L) ((\[CapitalLambda] *y - 
D2* z^-1)/-(\[CapitalLambda] *y* (D2/D1)^L - 
D1* (D2/D1)^L *z))) == 0, y];

H[x_, y_] = 
NSolve[z^(
2 L) - ((\[CapitalLambda] *x - 
D1* z) (\[CapitalLambda]* y* (D2/D1)^L - 
D1*(D2/D1)^L* z))/((\[CapitalLambda]* x - 
D2 *z^-1) (\[CapitalLambda] *y - D2*z^-1)) == 0, z];

H1[y_, s_] = H[x, y] /. x1;

H2[s_] = H1[y, s] /. Y1;

\[CapitalLambda][s_] = (D2*z^-1) + (D1* z) - dg;

Do[\[CapitalLambda][s] = Max[Re[\[CapitalLambda][s] /. H2[s]]], {s, 
smin, smax, \[CapitalDelta]s}];

p1 = ListLinePlot[
Table[{s, \[CapitalLambda][s]}, {s, smin, smax, \[CapitalDelta]s}], 
Frame -> True, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

Comment: I'm confused about your question, because your code runs fine without errors and makes a nice plot at the end: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jAhR2.png. Can you be more specific about what you need, and can you take out the parts of your code that are irrelevant to the question? Since you are asking above about `H2`, it's unclear what purpose the `Plot` has for your question.

Comment: Yes but for L=3 or more it doesn't work.I've just edited the L value

Comment: After your empty Plot shows up take a look at this: Table[{s, \\[CapitalLambda][s]}, {s, smin, smax, \\[CapitalDelta]s}] which will be a very large expression. Ask it to "show more" a few times until you can see enough details. You might even need to increase the magnification. What you should see is that it can't find the Max of the sum of sixth degree equations that involve both z and delta. From what you know about the problem can you see why you still have multiple variables and multiple terms in sixth degree equations with complicated denominators? Can that lead you to a solution?